# facebook graph api picture

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How can I retrieve friends picture using graph api.
I have manage to get my friends profile picture using this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}
```

But, I want to get the photos my friend has posted.

I am able to get this data

```
"link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=121312&set=a.23342344855.11344514&type=1",
     "name": "~KAALAM moments :)",
     "caption": "51 new photos",
     "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
     "actions": [
        {
           "name": "Comment",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1140004514/posts/12234"
        },
        {
           "name": "Like",
           "link": "http://www.facebook.com/1140004514/posts/12234"
        }
     ],
     "type": "photo",
     "object_id": "2554798026153",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your friend's pictures you will need

1. Valid access token with `friends_photos`
2. HTTP GET `\{friendId}\photos` to get photo's the friend is tagged in

or

1. Valid access token with `friends_photos`
2. HTTP GET `\{friendId}\albums` to get a friend's albums listing, loop thru it to get the photos in each album by `\{albumId}\photos`

Try it out here:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: ;) Coding is not always easy, otherwise millions of people would do it and our salaries would drop drastically

Comment: Yeah indeed, done it already. Come by to give some credits. Thanks by the way :)