# facebook graph api retrieve wall photos

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How Can I retrieve photos on the wall post., I only know how to get profile picture by using this `graph. https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture` but I don't know on wall photos.

Comment: Wall photo is a general wall post. Have you tried to look at the documentation?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, but no luck in wall photos. I can get my wall post by using the graph api but, photos that are posted by my friends I can't. Only links are given to me.

Comment: it would be great if you shown what requests you have tried and which don't work

Comment: here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036566/facebook-graph-api-picture) for additional details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It a three step process to obtain all the wall photos of a user

1. First make a request to obtain list of all the albums (me/albums)
2. Search the list obtain in first step for album name "Wall Photos"
3. use the id obtained in step 2 to get list of photos in that album. (356003227794989/photos)

and dont forget to have proper permission to access photos.